# Making a WooCommerce shortcode that searches the database for the custom fields

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am new to coding. I would like to have a search form that once they search for a certain serial number, it will find in the database and show other custom fields such as certificate, start date, and end date. The codes below are the furthest I have gone.

```
    function wpb_demo_shortcode() { global $wpdb;


$results = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id, o.`order_item_name`, om.`meta_value` as 'bcs',  (select  pm.`meta_value`  from   `wp_postmeta` as pm  WHERE  o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id AND  pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') as 'certificate',  (select  pm.`meta_value`  from   `wp_postmeta` as pm  WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id AND  pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') as 'serial' FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items` as o, `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` as om, `wp_postmeta` as pm WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id AND om.`meta_key` = 'bcs' AND  (select  pm.`meta_value`  from   `wp_postmeta` as pm  WHERE  o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id AND  pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') IS NOT null  AND   (select  pm.`meta_value`  from   `wp_postmeta` as pm  WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id AND  pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') IS NOT null ");



$serial = (isset( $_GET['$serial'] )) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['$serial']) : ''; ?> <form action="" method="get">   <label for="fname">Serial number:</label><br>   <input type="text" id="$serial" name="$serial"><br>   <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form> <?php $enteredSerial = $_GET['$serial']; searchSerial($enteredSerial); //echo $holder;

//ob_start();

 echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<th>Order ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Product Name</th>';
    echo '<th>BCS</th>';
    echo '<th>Serial</th>';
    echo '<th>Certificate</th>';
    echo '</tr>';


} 

function searchSerial($serial) {   echo $serial; }

add_shortcode('greeting', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

The frontend will show this
[Frontend Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miM5s.png)

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this by using custom meta boxes within the product or custom post type. I suggest using CMB2 (Plugin) once installed you can initialise your own meta box options for product posts and call them within your templates / search pages.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know how to call and set the database, the problem is that I do not know how to make the search form for it.